ICMP Destination unreachable with Accounting-Request replicate in freeradius
I am using the replicate function on the accounting section and everything works as expected: the destination server receives the message as intended, and freeradius continues working not worrying about the Accounting-Response. However, upon inspection of the traces, I can see that the Accounting response is answered with an ICMP error (Destination unreachable).
Is this the way that freeradius has to dettach himself from the response of the upstream server? Is there any way of preventing this from happening?
